# Closing popup window after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, blogger

**Popup is displayed after 6 seconds, yes then this works already.**
**I need to close the popup windows after 10 seconds.  How to change javascript?**

demo link http://helplogger-demo-blog2.blogspot.com/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.cookie = function(key, value, options) {
    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
        options = jQuery.extend({}, options);
        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }
        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires,
                t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }
        value = String(value);
        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
            options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }
    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var result, decode = options.raw ? function(s) {
        return s;
    } : decodeURIComponent;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};
//]]>
</script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($.cookie('popup_facebook_box') != 'yes') {
        $('#fbox-background').delay(5000).fadeIn('medium');
        $('#fbox-button, #fbox-close').click(function() {
            $('#fbox-background').stop().fadeOut('medium');
        });
    }
    $.cookie('popup_facebook_box', 'yes', {
        path: '/',
        expires: 7
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'd start by cleaning up your JS. Try running it through a [beautifier.](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: I've done it, please take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout function to achieve that

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){ 
    //close the popup here
    $('#fbox-background').stop().fadeOut('medium');
}, 10000);
```